# I am trying to submit a form through ajax in wordpress, but the result in the success callback gives me the page's markup in string

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

The first block of code is the javascript to send the form data without page refresh. The second block of code is the `functions.php` function to send the mail using PHP Mailer.

I can't understand why it is so different with Wordpress. Usually it is straight forward. I implemented the above using this tutorial: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tutorial-ajax-wordpress/

```
jQuery('#contactForm').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit() {
    var contactReplyForm = jQuery(this).serialize();
    if (jQuery(this).parsley().isValid()) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php get_template_directory_uri().'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'?>",
            data: contactReplyForm,
            success: function(result) {
                jQuery('div#contactFormSuccess' ).show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
                console.log(result);
            }
        });  
    }
    return false;
}
```

```php
function ajaxFormSubmission()
{
    $contact_form_name = $_POST['contact_form_name'];
    $contact_form_phone = $_POST['contact_form_phone'];
    $contact_form_email = $_POST['contact_form_email'];
    $contact_form_address = $_POST['contact_form_address'];
    $contact_form_comments = $_POST['contact_form_comments'];

    require_once (__DIR__."/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;         
    $mail->isSMTP();                              
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;               
    $mail->Username = "mnengwamkongo@gmail.com";                 
    $mail->Password = "Shadow-walker";              
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";       
    $mail->Port = 587; 

    $mail->From = $contact_form_email;
    $mail->FromName = $contact_form_name;

    $mail->addAddress("mnengwamkongo@gmail.com", "Kabugu and Co Advocates");

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = "Email from website";
    $mail->Body =   "Phone: ".$contact_form_phone."<br/>".
                    "Address: ".$contact_form_address."<br/>".
                    $contact_form_comments;
    $mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

    if(!$mail->send())
    {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Form Successfully Submitted!";
    }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxFormSubmission', 'ajaxFormSubmission');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxFormSubmission', 'ajaxFormSubmission');
```

Comment: Put a echo inside ajaxFormSubmission(){} function and check if ajax call goes upto the function or not?

Answer (score 1):

1. if you don`t know - the difference between these functions are

`add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxFormSubmission', 'ajaxFormSubmission');` // it will working only from admin role

`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxFormSubmission', 'ajaxFormSubmission');` //but it`s will be working with guest role

2. in Javascript code you have an an error

   ..........
     data: contactReplyForm,
   ..........

the data array must contains a name of handler function on your server

### your data array is like that

```
contactReplyForm = {
 action : 'ajaxFormSubmission', // name of handler function on your server
....
}
```

3. In file functions.php you must write

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 99 );

```
function myajax_data(){

    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_script.js')
    wp_localize_script('myscript', 'myajax', 
        array(
            'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        )
    );  
}
```

and change your Javascript code

```
...............
jQuery.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url: myajax.url,
             data: contactReplyForm,
...............
```

Comment: Thanks Yulia. Let me try that and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

So, sorry,  Matina Matina.

Better code is:

```
...............
jQuery.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url: myajax.url,
             data: { 
                    form_data: contactReplyForm,
                    action : 'ajaxFormSubmission'
...............
```