# Wordpress can't find data from custom posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am quite new to Wordpress so you'll have to forgive me if this is simple!

I have taken over a Wordpress website where a component that takes content from custom posts has stopped working. This is since the hosting have been changed. There is a php file (below) that just can't get the data anymore.

Any ideas why?

script.js

```
        $.ajax({
            url: BASE_DIR + '/events.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                ajaxResponse = response;
                init(ajaxResponse);
            }    
        });
```

events.php

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");

$parse_uri = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
require_once($parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php');

$response = array();

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'recurring_event',
    'meta_value' => '1'
);

$events = get_posts($args);

foreach ($events as $event) {

    $eventObj = array();

    $eventObj['id'] = $event->ID;
    $eventObj['title'] = $event->post_title;
    if (get_field('start_time', $event->ID)) {
        $eventObj['start'] = get_field('start_time', $event->ID);
    } else {
        $eventObj['start'] = '00:00';
    }
    $eventObj['day'] = get_field('days', $event->ID);
    $eventObj['url'] = get_the_permalink($event->ID);
    $eventObj['allDay'] = get_field('all_day_event', $event->ID);
    $eventObj['isMeeting'] = get_field('meeting_event', $event->ID);

    $response[] = $eventObj;

}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

I hope this is enough information, if not holler!

Comment: 1. So the only thing that changed is the hosting? 2. Is debugging turned on? 3. Is the ACF plugin installed and active?

Comment: Hi Dre, 1. yes hosting changed and actually all plugins and wordpress was updated, this could be it too! 2. No debugging is not turned on thanks for the tip I'll try that on a dev server. 3. ACF is installed and active.

Comment: The first things I'd check are that `BASE_DIR` in your JS and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME`] are both returning what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this code is not complete.
There apparently is also used for AJAX.
Can watch at this link how to work with AJAX in Wordpress

[I am trying to submit a form through ajax in wordpress, but the result in the success callback gives me the page's markup in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972095/i-am-trying-to-submit-a-form-through-ajax-in-wordpress-but-the-result-in-the-su/40972677#40972677)

Comment: Thanks Yulia I forgot to include that part. There is already an Ajax call in a JS script.